# Translation data not append is not working for full page in ajax success

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, microsoft-translator

can any one help me  here Please.if my question or code is not clear please tell me I'll explain some what briefly.

I am trying to translate page using Microsoft translator but its not working for HTML tag in Ajax success:

Data translation is working fine due to limitation of translation data i just slice the  elements and convert the innerhtml data ,in success of Ajax  unable to append the data which is convert to the page.

Can any one help me whats wrong with my code in ajax success?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTranslat').change(function (evt) {
 evt.preventDefault();
 var authToken = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_token').val();
 var from = 'en';
 var to = 'hi';
 var chunkdata = [];
 var data = $("*");
 var len = data.length;
 len = len / 2;
 len = Math.round(len);

  try {
   var startlen = 0;
   var endlen = 2;
   var endadd = 2;
  for (var i = 1; i <= len + 1; i++)
    {   
      chunkdata.push(data.slice(startlen, endlen));
      startlen = endlen + 1;
      endlen = endlen + endadd;
    }
   }
   catch (e) {
       throw e;
     }

     var divsplit = [];
       $.each(chunkdata, function (i, val) {
     var htmls = '';
       $.each(val, function (j, val2) {
         htmls = val2.innerHTML;
         divsplit.push(htmls);
   });
});

$("html").html('');
$.each(divsplit, function (i, val) {
if (divsplit[i] != "") {
  var data1 = {
  appId: 'Bearer ' + authToken,
  contentType: 'text/html',
  };
  $.ajax({
  url: "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?text=" + divsplit[i] + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data1,
  json: 'oncomplete',
  success: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  var $dom = $(document.createElement("html"));
  var appen = $dom.filter('html').append(jqXHR);
 },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log('fail', this, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
     }
   });
   }
  });
 });
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am  expecting result like bing translator for whole page  if any other example availble please provide me

Comment: Is jqXHR possibly a container for another object or property that contains your required data?  For instance: maybe it should be `var appen = $dom.filter('html').append(jqXHR.CustomProperty);`

If you use FireFox and FireBug, or some other debugger to show the exact JSON response you receive, could perhaps post a screenshot of the exact JSON result?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

`$(document).createElement("html")`

instead of

`$(document.createElement("html"))`

Also if you want to use jquery to create an element you might use:

`$(document).create("html")`

Comment: hi thanks Erik Cristian Seulean for reply but its not working for my scenior error:$(...).createElement is not a function(…)

Comment: then use $.create("html") or $("<html> </html>").append(things)

Comment: @ Erik Cristian Seulean  i tried for both  this approachs $.create("html")  ---eroor:create is not a function(…)  ,for                                                 this  $("<html> </html>").append(things) data is not appending u can see in above image it showing "" empty but in parameter jqXHR data is passing

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
success: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  var $dom = $(document.createElement("html"));
  var appen = $dom.filter('html').append(jqXHR);
}
```

By this:

```
success: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  $("html").replaceWith(jqXHR);
}
```

A few other issues I see with the code, first... you're missing an `appId`.

Second, the answer will be in `JSON` which means that your whole page might be swapped out to be a `JSON` string.

Let us know if it works out for you.

Comment: hi i am not missing appiId ,i am geting token from .aspx.cs page and save in "authToken" variable in my code.         second   :$("html").replaceWith(jqXHR); is not geting result as expecting why because i am sending translated data into array(chunks) so if i replacewiht one chunk remaining are not appending. please see the image above of result

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you

```
success: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  $("html").append(jqXHR);
}
```

`$("html").html('');` simply set the empty HTML content of the `html` element, so it's still in the DOM, page should have only one `html` element, when you adding additional `html` element `document.createElement("html")` it makes page invalid an could cause unexpected behaviour

Comment: i am working in .aspx page so it genrate some script in html page for event so its not showing expected resut is there any possiblity to replace those script in <head> tag
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
    var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
    if (!theForm) {
        theForm = document.form1;
    }
    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) { theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget; theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;  theForm.submit();  }  }//]]></script>

Comment: @stpdevi it isn't clear, is it ajax loaded content or not and what result you expecting?

Comment: if you see bing plugin  transltor how it translate page as it is i am tring to do with microsoft translator (i am doing in aspx page) while convert this page as html when i check in "view source" in browser i generating some script like above comment.because of i am unabel to get expected result how to exclude those script.